# Gentoo portage: list all variables emerge invoked with

Tags: gentoo, debug, portage

Is there an easy way to list all variables of emerge process?
I need to list all resulting variables after /etc/portage/env/* and /etc/portage/bashrc wiil be applyed to debug this scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Try with any of these commands

```
env
emerge --info
```